# The grep and find function in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

How do i search my /usr/bin directory for specific files? For example with the letter e and file size over a certain amout or under. I've already tried grep -i 'e' /user/bin   and find,but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can find all files in `/usr/bin` with size larger than `10000k` and with letter `e` in the name:

```
find /usr/bin -size +10000k -name '*e*'
```

Here is [manual page of find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

`grep` is used to search **contents** of files which doesn't make much sense with `/usr/bin` because many of these files are binary. Plus it's not possible to filter files by size with `grep`.

From [grep man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html):

```
grep searches the named input FILEs for lines 
containing a match to the given PATTERN.
```